# How to use EventEmitter to pass function to a child component?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a parent-child component setup where on (tap) event on an element in child, i need to invoke a parent method. I am trying the eventEmmiter but am getting this error:

> Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "events",
>   relative to: app/tns_modules/

**Code snippet**

*Parent.component.html*

```
<app-header (thisEvent)="navigate($event)"></app-header>
```

*Parent.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "app-main",
  templateUrl: "./parent.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./parent.component.css"]
})
export class ParentComponent {
naviagte(args){
this.router.navigate(["/"]);
}
}
```

*Child.component.html:*

```
<Button text="Tap" class="btn btn-primary" (tap)="onTap($event)"></label>
```

*Child.component.ts:*

```
import { Component, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
@Component({
  selector: "app-header",
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output()
  thisEvent= new EventEmitter();
  navigate(args) {
    this.thisEvent.emit(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should import `EventEmitter` from `@angular/core` not from `events`.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
```

Answer (score 0):

Error you get is due to wrong import

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
```

[EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#usage-notes) should be import from **angular/core** package

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

EventEmitter from "@angular/core"